# ActionBarSherlock and new Android SDK

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I had an existing project working with ActionBarSherlock and the android SDK (tools version 19 i think) i upgraded the Android SDK to the latest version (21) and suddenly all the R variable stuff is missing, example: R.layout.fragment_account_layout it claims does not exist and needs to be created. pretty much everything related to the R variable is messed up. i have tried a couple different things to fix it; cleaned the project, cleared out the workspace and re-added everything. nothing has worked. how i do resolve this issue? is it a change i need to make to my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check that your activities are not importing the wrong R file ( In this case it may be importing the R from the ActionBarSherlock instead of your application)
Worst case you may need to add manually your R into your activities.
like

`import your.app.namespace.R;`

within the class and delete any other R being imported